# JPA SequenceGenerator

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, sequence

Entity class

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "generator1")
@SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "sequence2", name = "generator1",
allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
private int                id;
```

Main

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Employee");
                entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
                 Employee us = new Employee();
                us.setFirstname("John");
                us.setLastname("John");
                entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
                entityManager.persist(us);
                entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

The first ID number will be 1, but when I run it again it creates an ID number 3 (it should be 2 ?) and i dont know why. What is wrong here ?

Comment: Are you using that sequence for another entity as well ?

Comment: Can you check what sequence JPA generated in your DB ? (What schema did it generate for the sequence)

Comment: CREATE SEQUENCE hibernate_sequence
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 36
  CACHE 1;
ALTER TABLE hibernate_sequence
  OWNER TO postgres;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is logical when you use `Postgres`.
As the minimal (and default) cache size is `1`, when you insert an entity with id `1` it prefetch `2`.

Section [9.16. Sequence Manipulation Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-sequence.html) of the Postgres Manual indicates:

`Important: To avoid blocking concurrent transactions that obtain numbers from the same sequence, a nextval operation is never rolled back; that is, once a value has been fetched it is considered used, even if the transaction that did the nextval later aborts. This means that aborted transactions might leave unused "holes" in the sequence of assigned values.`

Which means, if you fetch `2` and end up not using it, it will not be reused.

That is why you see `3` after `1`.

Regardless of all that, you should keep in mind that such a low cache size has an impact on performance and is not recommended.

Comment: Heh, I wrote that documentation snippet when it became clear this was a common misunderstanding :-) . One thing you need to realize: This has *nothing* to do with the sequence cache in PostgreSQL. Even with a sequence cache size of 1, holes will still appear if you rollback after a `nextval` call or in any other way call `nextval` without storing the result. Sequences *just have gaps* and *there is nothing you can do about it*. If you need gapless you have to accept a terrible performance penalty. Search for "postgresql gapless sequence".

Comment: But the cache size will affect the size of holes, isn't it ? If the cache size was 5 wouldn't he get a whole of 5 in this case ?